# alert() not working with PhoneGap on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm trying out PhoneGap 1.4 on Windows Phone 7.5 using jQuery mobile (1.0.1.). 
Basic navigation is working, unfortuantely I can't seem to get alerts working. Neither alert("string); nor PhoneGap's navigator.notification.alert(message, alertCallback, [title], [buttonName]); get me any response. The PhoneGap test message is being displayed fine. This is the way I try to call it:

```
function init()
{
  document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
}

function onDeviceReady()
{
  document.getElementById("welcomeMsg").innerHTML += "PhoneGap is ready!";
  alert('test');
  navigator.notification.alert(
      'You are the winner!',  // message
      alertDismissed,         // callback            
      'Game Over',            // title            
      'Done'                  // buttonName        
  );
}
```

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/e3053e90aaf4890b

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Weird though, that the navigator.notification.alert() with all the options as posted above (copied from the phonegap homepage) doesn't work...

Comment: hmmm, weird it is. accept n close then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See this [Google Groups discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/phonegap/browse_thread/thread/e3053e90aaf4890b).

In short, Windows Phone 7 IE9 web browser doesn't support alerts, and instead you must use the PhoneGap Notification API, like this:

```
navigator.notification.alert("Message", callBackMethod, "Title", "Button Text");
```

For further information, see the [PhoneGap Notification API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_notification_notification.md.html#notification.alert).

Comment: Strange, but the example does not work on my WP 7.8 and WP 8. I use PhoneGap 3.4.0. Problem description: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18042909/phonegap-build-navigator-notification-alert-not-working-in-wp7-emulator/18731585#18731585