# PhoneGap Build - navigator.notification.alert not working in WP7 emulator

Tags: phonegap-build, windows-phone-7-emulator

I build this simple code with PGB, but it does not working in WP7 emulator - no alert message.
For android emulator its ok.
What's wrong?

```
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {
        navigator.notification.alert("Device Ready!");
    }
```

Source code https://github.com/dprotopopov/pgb-wp7-alert

Comment: were you able to make it work ?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a bug with the latest PhoneGap build for WP7. I have this up and running in Visual Studio and although the navigator object is accessible in the code there is no notification property available. You can test the same yourself by iterating through the properties of the navigator object in your app;

```
for(var key in navigator){
   document.write(key + "<br>");
}
```

The list I get is as follows, note that notification is not one of them :(

- appCodeName
- appMinorVersion
- browserLanguage
- cookieEnabled
- cpuClass
- mimeTypes
- plugins
- systemLanguage
- userLanguage
- msDoNotTrack
- geolocation
- appName
- appVersion
- platform
- userAgent
- onLine
- javaEnabled
- taintEnabled

Comment: So, what to do to make the navigator.notification.alert work as it is not displayed in the list so what is the solution ??

Comment: I would suggest running the code above in the latest PhoneGap build (since this answer is almost 2 years old) and if the notification property is still not there engaging with the PhoneGap community. If this method isn't supported on the Windows platform you would need to code a custom workaround by checking for a Windows Phone in your code and triggering a notification manually, for instance with a basic Javascript alert()